# Make data not disappear from file field using codeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have filled 10 fields out of 11 fields including **selected the file for upload the document**. after submitting, the error is a message showing one field data is required at the **same time the file field document value also disappeared.**

I am using the following method but still, value is disappeared while clicking submit button.

```html
<input  class="form-control" type="file" class="form-control" id= "userfile" name= "userfile" value="<php? echo set_value('userfile');?>">
```

Kindly help me to rectify the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not keep the selected file. You can read about it and what you can do about it here.

- [php keep the value of file fields when validating a form returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8839525/12731030)

Another solution - You can implement a step by step process. In the first step, you can get text inputs and validate them. If it succeed, then you can continue to the image upload page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jquery so that when the user clicks on the submit button you check that all fields are fine and then you submit the form.

```
$("#submit_button").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //code to check that all fields are fine
    $("#my_form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think validation available in Codeigniter itself but the value should be keep in the file field after clicking the submit button while other fields are not filled up.